# Codeigniter bootstrap load only on index.php page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm loading bootstrap this way on my view page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>">
```

**autoload:**  `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

**configs:**  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/helloby/';`

Below is the path of the controller:

http://localhost/helloby/index.php/login/home

But when I copy the same code at welcome_message view bootstrap loads normally. I don't know why it's happening.

Comment: The best way is to always view your html source code in your browser. That will let you see what is being generated. It's a very good debug tool to show you what is happening instead of guessing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I was reading an e-book of best practice of Codeigniter and the call of bootstrap was a little bit different.

This way : `href="<?=base_url('/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>`

and working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[site_url()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url)** instead of **base_url()**

base_url returns the url without index.php

Check if you are loading the bootstrap css in every view, you cant just load it in one view and expect that all other views know about it.

Common way of doing things like this is to create header and footer files that are shared between all views.

Comment: Are you loading that css file in every view? After re-reading your question it seems that you only load bootstrap css file in your index view.

Comment: problem solved I shared in the answer! thanks for the attention!